# Immutable resource cannot be modified (DataMapper::ImmutableError)

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I have a list of comments stored in a database. I can pull the comment from the database and manipulate it, however, I get the error when I try to update my database again via datamapper.

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/resource/state/immutable.rb:16:in `set': Immutable resource cannot be modified (DataMapper::ImmutableError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/model/property.rb:238:in `body='
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:334:in `block in attributes='
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:330:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:330:in `attributes='
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/resource.rb:379:in `update'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-validations-1.1.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:75:in `block in update'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-validations-1.1.0/lib/dm-validations/support/context.rb:30:in `validation_context'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-validations-1.1.0/lib/dm-validations.rb:75:in `update'
from process.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from process.rb:28:in `each_line'
from process.rb:28:in `block in <main>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/collection.rb:507:in `block in each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/support/lazy_array.rb:411:in `block in each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/support/lazy_array.rb:411:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/support/lazy_array.rb:411:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/collection.rb:504:in `each'
from process.rb:27:in `<main>'
```

And here's the code:

```
comments.each do |comment|
  comment.body.each_line do |comment_line|
    comment_line = comment_line.lstrip
      if comment_line[0]== '>'
        new_comment = comment.body.slice! comment_line
        comment.update(:body => new_comment)
        comment.save
      end
   end
 end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be your `slice!`? Why not use `slice`?

Comment: @mu That's left over from some older code. The slice doesn't need to happen in place so I've changed it. I still get the same issue though.

Comment: How are you selecting the comments?  Can we see that code?  Also, the properties header from the model itself. You get immutable resources (by design) if you omit the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to call `comment.save` - remove it and it's possible it will work

Comment: @solnic: I just had this error and your fix worked. Could you elaborate on what's going on here?